# Flash a JP Sony Xperia 5 II (A00SO) to a global Vodafone LC Net Locked (XQ-AS52) firmware

Tags: rom-flashing, device-firmware, sony-xperia

Can I flash a JP Sony Xperia 5 II (A00SO) to a global Vodafone LC Not Net Locked (XQ-AS52) firmware?

And what is different between Vodafone LC Net Locked and Not Locked?

Comment: Usually branded/net locked firmwares have a different signature than the global unlocked firmware so the device will not accept it, even if the hardware is the same.